# Android HTTP Post Request to IIS 7 Returns Bad Request(Invalid Header Name)

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-ec2, iis-7.5, http-status-code-400

I have a MVC 3 Web Sevice being hosted on an Amazon EC2 Instance. I have an android app that is making a post request to the service. However a 400 bad request is returned saying that the header name is invalid. I checked the logs on the server and the request does not make it into IIS. The HTTP Err Log just has these entries:

2011-10-07 02:01:05 xxx.xxx.xx.xx xxxxx xx.xxx.xx.xx 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /API/UserAccount/Login 400 - Header -

Not really sure what is going on. I tested this web service on the developement server that comes with visual studio and there was no problems. Here is the code that creates the post request on Android:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
    "application/json"));
post.setEntity(se);
response = client.execute(post);
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the way you're setting the Http headers.  Here's an updated version of your code:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
se.setContentType("application/json");
post.setEntity(se);
response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: I almost spent whole morning & then found it. Very Very thanks.

Comment: What is happening here technically?  I'm in control of a server, but not the client, and a client is seeing this, but I can't see the problem with the headers I'm receiving from them.