# HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Java application with the below code. I am trying to invoke a REST web service using HttpClient POST. I need to send a custom header "auth" for authentication. The value of the header is the encrypted credentials separated by a ":".

```
        String strAuth = DoAESEncrypt("userid:pwd");
        String strContent = DoAESEncrypt("{\"Name\":Tester,\"Id\":\"123\",\"NickName\":null,\"IsLocked\":false}");

          HttpClient client =  new DefaultHttpClient();          
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://domainname/servicename");
          post.addHeader("auth",strAuth);
          post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          StringEntity input = new StringEntity(strContent);
          post.setEntity(input);
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

The DoAESEncrypt is a function that encrypts the input string and returns the Cipher. However, when I run this code, I get the below error where I have the statement client.execute:

> HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name

However, if I hard-code the below header with the encrypted Cipher I generated using the same DoAESEncrypt function, it works fine:

```
      post.addHeader("auth","5PE7vNMYVFJT/tgYo7TGuPO05lqMQx5w3BAJKDS567A73vM0TYFmWO5tP=");
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682514/android-http-post-request-to-iis-7-returns-bad-requestinvalid-header-name

Comment: @Lubo I do not have issue with setting Content Type. It works with the way I am doing it now. However, the issue is with the custom header "auth".

Comment: If you hardcode the value of `auth` it works, but when you use `strAuth` is doesn't? So what is the value of `strAuth`?

Comment: @Andreas  if I set strAuth = DoAESEncrypt("userid:password"), it does not work. However, if I hard code strAuth = "5PE7vNMYVFJT/tgYo7TGuPO05lqMQx5w3BAJKDS567A73vM0TYFmWO5tP=" (this is exactly the response I get DoAESEncrypt), it works.

Comment: If it is the *exact same* value, then hardcoding would make no difference.

Comment: @Andreas It too think the same. But, this is weird.

Comment: This might be the problem, you forgot to escape the quotation mark around userid `DoAESEncrypt("userid:pwd")` vs  `DoAESEncrypt("\"userid\":pwd");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the DoAESEncrypt function was adding a carriage return "\r\n" to the Cipher text. This was removed and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
String strAuth = DoAESEncrypt("userid:pwd");
        String strContent = DoAESEncrypt("{\"Name\":Tester,\"Id\":\"123\",\"NickName\":null,\"IsLocked\":false}");

          HttpClient client =  new DefaultHttpClient();          
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://domainname/servicename");
          post.addHeader("auth",strAuth.replace("\n","").replace("\r","");
          post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          StringEntity input = new StringEntity(strContent);
          post.setEntity(input);
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

> Replace all \n and \r from your encrypted string which you passing to
>   header as follow

```
strAuth.replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
```

Comment: Worked for me!!